# Rep threshold for answering your own question?

Tags: discussion, answering-questions

According to the asker of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/300646/mod-auth-mysql-dont-validate) (see the last couple of comments), he doesn't have enough rep to answer his own question.  However, I can't see any mention of a rep threshold for self-answering in [the FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq#reputation).  Am I missing something in the FAQ, is the FAQ missing something, or is the questioner just fundamentally confused?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a waiting period, rather than a rep-threshold. I'll look it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is a waiting period, rather than a reputation threshold. 8 hours it looks like:

[Minimum reputation for answering your own question should be higher than what is needed to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186)

It used to be 24 hours, but got bumped back to 8.

Also, I know from recent experience that there is a 48 hour waiting period to accept an answer you post yourself.